# Animation not working after Halting in Edge

Tags: css, css-animations, microsoft-edge

I have bounce animation on my page, which bounces five times initially, and then bounces again on hover, this is working on Chrome and Firefox (Perfectly), but on IE, after first 5 times of bouncing, the animation does not happen when I hover.

```
.animate>#icon {
   -webkit-animation: bounce 2s ease 5;
   -moz-animation: bounce 2s ease 5;
   -ms-animation: bounce 2s ease 5;
   animation: bounce 2s ease 5;
}
.animate:hover>#icon {
   -webkit-animation: bounce 2s ease infinite;
   -moz-animation: bounce 2s ease infinite;
   -ms-animation: bounce 2s ease infinite;
   animation: bounce 2s ease infinite;
}
```

The Hover is working fine, as I tried testing the hover issue on IE, (by adding a display: none; property), it is working as expected, but the animation is not starting once it has stopped. Any ideas or workarounds for the same would be really appreciated.

Comment: I think it's likely that you've run into a bug (this is IE, after all). What happens if you remove the non-hover animation? Is it infinite?

Comment: @Harangue, if I remove the non-hover animation, it works perfectly on hover. (As it should).